# Python annotation - why does my IDE's Intellisense not recognise a known class?

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub, python-typing

I am using client library google-cloud-pubsub in order to to interact with Google Cloud Platform's Pub/Sub service. There is a class in that library called `google.cloud.pubsub_v1.types.Subscription`, documentation for which appears at https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/types.html.

I am using this library successfully an am able to interact with a Pub/Sub subscription using something like the following:

```py
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

def myfunc(project_id, subscription):
  subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
  subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription.name)
  # do something using the subscription...
```

I'm now trying to be a good python citizen and use type annotations in my code. I know that the value passed to the `subscription` argument will be of type `google.cloud.pubsub_v1.types.Subscription` so I'd like to write the appropriate type annotation, but I'm getting a bit confused about the behaviour that I am seeing. My editor's (my editor is VSCode) intellisense understands about `pubsub_v1.types` module:

[image]

However it doesn't seem to know about the `Subscription` class therein:

[image]

Same on PyCharm, it knows about `google.cloud.pubsub_v1.types`:
[image]

but not `google.cloud.pubsub_v1.types.Subscription`

[image]

I am struggling to understand why this might be so am hoping someone can explain it to me.

---

In case it helps, here's how i set up a virtualenv for this:

```
➜  /tmp python3 -m venv venv
➜  /tmp source venv/bin/activate
(venv) ➜  /tmp python -m pip install google-cloud-pubsub
Collecting google-cloud-pubsub
  Downloading google_cloud_pubsub-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (217 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 217 kB 1.6 MB/s
Collecting grpcio<2.0dev,>=1.38.1
  Using cached grpcio-1.39.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (3.9 MB)
Collecting grpc-google-iam-v1<0.13dev,>=0.12.3
  Using cached grpc-google-iam-v1-0.12.3.tar.gz (13 kB)
Collecting libcst>=0.3.10
  Downloading libcst-0.3.20-py3-none-any.whl (514 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 514 kB 2.5 MB/s
Collecting proto-plus>=1.7.1
  Using cached proto_plus-1.19.0-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting packaging>=14.3
  Using cached packaging-21.0-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=1.26.0
  Downloading google_api_core-1.31.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 93 kB 2.8 MB/s
Collecting googleapis-common-protos<2.0dev,>=1.6.0
  Using cached googleapis_common_protos-1.53.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (198 kB)
Collecting google-auth<2.0dev,>=1.25.0
  Downloading google_auth-1.34.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (152 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 152 kB 1.9 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=40.3.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from google-api-core[grpc]<3.0.0dev,>=1.26.0->google-cloud-pubsub) (54.1.2)
Collecting pytz
  Using cached pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Collecting protobuf>=3.12.0
  Using cached protobuf-3.17.3-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
Collecting requests<3.0.0dev,>=2.18.0
  Using cached requests-2.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting six>=1.13.0
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached cachetools-4.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting rsa<5,>=3.1.4
  Using cached rsa-4.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1
  Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Collecting pyyaml>=5.2
  Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (259 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.7.4.2
  Using cached typing_extensions-3.10.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting typing-inspect>=0.4.0
  Using cached typing_inspect-0.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.4 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.0.2
  Using cached pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6
  Using cached pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-3.2-py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer~=2.0.0
  Downloading charset_normalizer-2.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting mypy-extensions>=0.3.0
  Using cached mypy_extensions-0.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.5 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for grpc-google-iam-v1, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: six, pyasn1, urllib3, rsa, pyparsing, pyasn1-modules, protobuf, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, cachetools, typing-extensions, requests, pytz, packaging, mypy-extensions, grpcio, googleapis-common-protos, google-auth, typing-inspect, pyyaml, google-api-core, proto-plus, libcst, grpc-google-iam-v1, google-cloud-pubsub
    Running setup.py install for grpc-google-iam-v1 ... done
Successfully installed cachetools-4.2.2 certifi-2021.5.30 charset-normalizer-2.0.4 google-api-core-1.31.1 google-auth-1.34.0 google-cloud-pubsub-2.7.0 googleapis-common-protos-1.53.0 grpc-google-iam-v1-0.12.3 grpcio-1.39.0 idna-3.2 libcst-0.3.20 mypy-extensions-0.4.3 packaging-21.0 proto-plus-1.19.0 protobuf-3.17.3 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 pyparsing-2.4.7 pytz-2021.1 pyyaml-5.4.1 requests-2.26.0 rsa-4.7.2 six-1.16.0 typing-extensions-3.10.0.0 typing-inspect-0.7.1 urllib3-1.26.6
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.0.1; however, version 21.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/private/tmp/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: The difference is likely that `types.py` is a file easily found in the file system, while `Subscriptions` can only be found by actually reading, parsing, and potentially *evaluating* the contents of `types.py`.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to give my IDE some guidance around this? just feels wrong to me that I can successfully use a variable of that type in my executing code but the IDE is unaware of it.

Comment: The IDE *will* be aware of it once you import it. Don't take any IDE too seriously in these matters: they are all using various hacks and heuristics to work around the fact that source code itself is not structured. Especially in a dynamic language like Python, full introspection of a module is impossible before that module is actually defined by executing the contents of the file.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll accept that as an explanation :)